# How to update a field of a table with some percentage of its value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let suppose I have a table Employee, which have three field i.e EID , Salary, Dept

What I want to do is to increase the salary of every employee of Department 'Accounts' by 5%.

How this could be achieved in SQL Sever Query?

Kindly help me out!

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
update Mytable set Sal=1.05*sal where departmentId=xxx
```

Answer (score 8):

you can simply create an update statement with the right math. I would do something like this:

```
 update Employee set salary = (salary * 1.05) where Dept = 'Accounts'
```