# How do I update a record by adding a constant to its current value in flask sqlachemy?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying update a record in sql server db table by adding a certain a certain value to its current value but I want to do so using flask sql alchemy. How do I go about it. Here is the sql statement that I want to convert to flask sqlalchemy form.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = MyColumn + 2000
WHERE SomePhoneNumber = '+19023456789'
```

Note that this question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555189/how-to-update-a-field-of-a-table-with-some-percentage-of-its-value-in-sql).

Comment: See the answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334824/how-to-increase-a-counter-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

```
record = MyTable.query.filter(SomePhoneNumber='+19023456789').first()
record = record.MyColumn + 2000
record.save()
```

`.first()` will give you first element by that value and will not throw exception

`.one()` will throw exception if there is more than one element by that value.